# Pig Script error

Tags: hadoop, compiler-errors, apache-pig

When I try to execute the below Pig script in my cloudera VM I am getting following error

```
grunt> sta1 = LOAD 'hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/cloudera/movies_data.csv' USING
              PigStorage(',') AS (sno:int, moviename:chararray, year:int, rating:float, collect:int);
```

> **2014-10-05 07:34:19,670 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve
>   pigstorage using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin.,
>   org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]    Details at logfile:
>   /home/cloudera/pig_1412519459490.log**

Comment: This error is because of PigStorage(','), i think when you loaded the dataset you might have given small caps for p and s in PigStorage(',')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is because of the delimiter symbol doesn't match the PigStorage(',') in the .csv file in the hdfs. Make sure the corresponding .jar(macros) files are embedded in to the pig.

Answer (score 0):

-Dpig.additional.jars use this argument to add the jars required for pig to run.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Cloudera Manager is up from the VM Browser.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thank you for your post, however, for future reference if your post does not contain substantial code/instructions, leave it under the comments section